# css box shadow property is not working in safari

Tags: css

```
box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px 6px;
```

this property is working in chrome firefox IE but not in safari 5 browser

I tried writing like this but it isn't working

```
-webkit-box-shadow:3px 3px 6px 6px;
```

Comment: could be a CSS rendering issue with safari on ur machine..try the same on a different safari on a different pc.

Answer (score 28):

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px 6px #addacolor;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px 6px #addacolor;
```

Comment: In my case -webkit-appearance: none helped;

Answer (score 6):

you haven't defined color here (`box-shadow: h-shadow v-shadow blur spread color inset;`)

> [**`<color>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) If not specified, the color used depends on the browser - it is usually the value of the color property, but note that Safari currently paints a transparent shadow in this case.

so define color for safari

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px 6px #color_you_want;
```

Comment: I really appreciate comment with down vote .. and trust me i am not stereotype who do revenge down vote :)

Answer (score 3):

For reference, I had a similar problem with this box-shadow :

`box-shadow: 0 0.06rem 0 0 rgba(44, 43, 63, 0.1);`  (very small shadow!)

It was working in other browsers except for Safari(v.8) who didn't show that shadow. I had to increase the value.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with

```
-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
```

Comment: @alliprashanth you're welcome if you found this helpful feel free to up vote or mark it as the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
#example1 {
-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
 box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
 }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow

http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/