# Box-shadow doesn't display in Safari when using large values

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I am developing a small library/plugin with JavaScript to highlight different page sections in an animated way (with the intention to create instructions or similar), but I am finding some issues, specially with Safari.

For the highlighting, I use `box-shadow` because it is more widely supported than `clip-path`. I create a spotlight element with two box shadows: one is internal/inset (to give a gradient effect) and another outside (that will cover everything on the page but the highlighted element).

Here is some code with a minimal, complete, and verifiable example:

```css
#sp-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#sp-focus {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.8), 0 0 0 200vmax rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

```html
<div id="sp-frame">
  <div id="sp-focus">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

---

The idea is for it to look like this (positioned on top of the element to be highlighted):

[image: correct shadow]

But the problem is that on iPhone and Safari it looks like this:

[image: incorrect shadow]

---

I tried different solutions that I found both in Stack Overflow in English  ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18953282/3695983)) and in Spanish ([2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/66224/250) and [3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/73903/250)), like using the vendor prefixes `-webkit-box-shadow` and `-moz-box-shadow`, or `-webkit-appearance`... but it didn't fix the issue.

For iPhone, I was able to solve the problem in a strange way: if instead of using `border-radius: 100%`, it was `border-radius: 99%`, the shadow looks fine (like the first image). But still it breaks on Safari on a desktop/laptop.

Initially I thought it could be a problem with the `vmax` units ([Safari supports it](https://caniuse.com/#search=vmax)), as using a `px` value (e.g. 200px) made it work. So I tried calculating the max of width/height of the screen with JavaScript and assigning that value * 2 to the `box-shadow`... but after running some tests, it didn't work either.

The real problem seems to be that Safari doesn't display a shadow if it's larger than X pixels independently of units (X being a value around the size of the screen). And that is an issue because I need the shadow to be larger than the screen size to avoid having non-shaded areas.

Is this a bug? How can I solve this issue or go around it?

Comment: @KoshVery thanks for pointing to that question, it's definitely the same problem. The workaround of using border seems to work for me after doing some extra operations. Do you know if it is a known bug or why it is failing?