# Safari box-shadow bug?

Tags: css, safari, hover

I have an element with padding, on *:hover* I set the *background-color* and the *box-shadow*

(when hovering) Safari seems to have problems properly filling the area with the new *background-color*. Works as expected once I remove the *box-shadow* attribute from the hover event...

**How to keep box-shadow and fix the problem for Safari?**

```css
.btn,
a.btn{
    background-color: #027BFF;
    padding: 42px 20px;
}

.btn:hover, a.btn:hover {
    background-color: pink;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #888;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="javascript: something()"><span>Search</span></a>
```

Comparison:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [css box shadow property is not working in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953282/css-box-shadow-property-is-not-working-in-safari)

Comment: You might want to try `-webkit-appearance: none;`

Comment: @Greeky: That *unanswered* post from 2013 (9 years ago) does not answer my question, nope

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add position **relative**

```css
.btn {
    background-color: #027BFF;
    padding: 42px 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: pink;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #888;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="javascript: something()"><span>Search</span></a>
```

What about use **button** tag?

```css
.btn {
    background-color: #027BFF;
    padding: 42px 20px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: pink;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #888;
}
```

```html
<button href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="javascript: something()"><span>Search</span></button>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. (I cannot change to <button> because the html elements are in too many places across an app that multiple developers work on, so easier to just change the CSS code in one place)